# Passing confidence level to ACF plot

Tags: r

I have the following time series data:

```
x <- ts(c(-3151, -873, 135, 825, 1531, -1420, -282, 
    2113, -916, -2222, -4654, -604, -1322, 
   -15457, 13835, 446, 1402, -1230, 1790, 1374, 1463))
```

By default the autocorrelation function plots lines at 95% confidence:

```
acf(x)
```

(see blue dashed lines in the picture below)

[image]

Is there a way to pass in 90% confidence levels to this plot instead of the default 95% levels?  For instance, this does not work

```
acf(x, level=90)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Confidence Intervals to plotted ACF in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753017/adding-confidence-intervals-to-plotted-acf-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Looking at `?acf` we see that there's `...` meaning "*further arguments to be passed to `plot.acf`*". Checking `?plot.acf` show that the following works:

```
acf(x, ci = 0.90)
```

[image]